# echo a quoted array as quoted

Tags: arrays, bash

The following code

```
myopts=( --url="http://www.lemonde.fr" --out="hello world" --out-format="png" )
echo "going to execute following command: cutycapt ${myopts[@]}"
# commented out because this way you do not have to have cutycapt to test
# cutycapt "${myopts[@]}"
```

outputs the following:

```
going to execute following command: cutycapt --url=http://www.lemonde.fr --out=hello world --out-format=png
```

but really what is executed is:

```
cutycapt --url="http://www.lemonde.fr" --out="hello world" --out-format="png"
```

Thus, that is what I would like to be output from the `echo` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf` with the `%q` format string to print a quoted version of the arguments like

```
printf '%q ' cutycapt "${myopts[@]}"; printf '\n'
```

(we add our `\n` to the end since `printf` doens't automatically add one)

Example:

```
$ myopts=( --url="http://www.lemonde.fr" --out="hello world" --out-format="png" )
$ printf 'going to execute following command: '; printf '%q ' cutycapt "${myopts[@]}"; printf '\n'
going to execute following command: cutycapt --url=http://www.lemonde.fr --out=hello\ world --out-format=png
```

with the escape of the space in `hello world`

Depending on why you want this, have you considered just running with `set -x` enabled, so you see the expanded command line before it's executed anyway?

```
$ set -x
$ cutycapt "${myopts[@]}"
+ cutycapt --url=http://www.lemonde.fr '--out=hello world' --out-format=png
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create your array, its elements are subject to quote removal. If you want to keep them, you have to add them quoted already:

```
$ myopts=( '--url="http://www.lemonde.fr"' '--out="hello world"' '--out-format="png"' )
$ echo "going to execute following command: cutycapt ${myopts[@]}"
going to execute following command: cutycapt --url="http://www.lemonde.fr" --out="hello world" --out-format="png"
```

If you look at your array elements after creating `myopts`, you'll see that they're already missing the quotes:

```
$ myopts=( --url="http://www.lemonde.fr" --out="hello world" --out-format="png" )
$ (IFS=$'\n'; echo "${myopts[*]}")
--url=http://www.lemonde.fr
--out=hello world
--out-format=png
```

So it's not the expansion that removes them – it happens when assigning.

Comment: but when I use your `myopts`, the command `cutycapt ${myopts[@]}` does not work. I do not want to have two separate `myopts` because I would like to reduce duplication.

Comment: How do @XuWang How do you actually call it? `cutycapt "${myopts[@]}"` (notice the quotes)?

Comment: Yes sorry with the quotes is how I call it. It does not work for me.